# Have one line and I want 1 from that one

Tags: qgis, line

I have one line layer which is made up of multiple segments. I want each segment to be a new line feature so that I can select them individually using select features by area, as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: What software are you using? QGIS? ESRI ArcGIS? Something else?

Comment: What (geometry type/feature type) are we looking at here? Is this a single 4-segment linestring? An area (polygon)? 4 single-segment linestrings?

Comment: You must split the geometry first into segments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks from the graphic like you're using QGIS, in which case you have a couple of steps, depending on whether you're looking at a polygon or a polyline.

If your layer is a polygon - start at 1
If your layer is a line - start at 2

1. Open Vector > Geometry Tool > Polygons to lines : this will convert the polygon to lines.
2. Open the processing toolbox > Explode Lines (you can find it by searching 'explode') : this will split all of your lines at their vertices to give you individual lines so you'll be able to select features by area and just get the one line.